# How two applications running in same JVM or server interact with other?

Tags: java, jvm

Need to know how to make two applications running in same JVM interact with each other without using web services or JMS, ESB? can JNDI be used? if yes please provide me some example. Thanks.

Comment: You may be able to use queues if you are able to pass the queue handles to both parts of the application on startup. For more detail, please indicate in which way they are separate applications in the same JVM.

Comment: @Jason - I have two web applications (say web1 and web2) of Java and they both are running in same JVM to interact with one another, and am not encouraged to use ESB, JMS, Queues, SOAP, REST.

Comment: You don't want to use these techniques or have a requirement not to use it? Depending on the task, you can always use the database to communicate between the two applications by having the two parts share access to a table. This may or may not be a good idea depending on what is being communicated and the data volume.

Comment: What about shared memory?  There are several different shared memory libs that you can use - ex: HazelCast, InfiniSpan, Terracotta, etc.  Would you be able to interact via some shared memory space and maybe some form of queuing?  What about via a common DB?  Can you use JMX?